# MathJax buggy on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, markdown, mathjax

On Stack Overflow, it appears that MathJax has been enabled. I have two problems apparently caused by MathJax.

1. If someone places backticks in a title, the title no longer displays correctly. See, for example, [Module can import at console, but not within script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177939/module-can-import-at-console-but-not-within-script#16177939). The title on that page should render as: "Module can `import` at console, but not within script", but actually renders as: "Module can *imp* or *t* at console, but not within script".
2. Whenever I edit a comment, the markdown source of my comment is incorrect. Every backticked phrase is repeated.

I am using Chrome 26.0.1410.63 on Ubuntu 10.04.4.

Is this problem global? Does everyone see this? If so, how do I bring it to the attention of the powers-that-be?

Or is this problem isolated? Is it just me? If so, what do I change in my environment to fix it?

Comment: You're in the right place to bring it to the attention of those who could do something about this. That said, as stated by @Manishearth, there is no MathJax on SO.

Comment: MathJax is available only on math.SE (and maybe on tex.SE).

Comment: @hjpotter92 and several of the science sites - biology, chemistry, physics etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MathJax is not enabled on SO, you may have a userscript or extension interfering.

Besides, mathjax doesn't touch backticks.

Comment: That makes sense to me. But, when I right-click "Inspect Element" on the question title, I see MathJax markup tags, and the <head> has a "<script src=http://cdn.mathjax.org ...". From that I inferred that SO had turned on MathJax.

Comment: @Rob: It's only there for you. Go to chrome://extensions and check if there are any runaway extensions or userscripts.

Comment: Yep. I had "MathJax for Chrome" extension installed and activated. Deleting it made everything all better. Thanks for pointing it out.